# Excel Interop: Quitting the Excel application instance makes my tests fail?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I want to encapsulate the use of Excel Interop to make it easier to use somehow in a reuseable library.

So far, I have written some tests that work good altogether, except that between each test, I force Excel to quite so that it does have handle on the test file no more in order to be able to delete.

Once I quit the application instance between after each of my tests, Excel seems to be no longer responding, causing Windows to display

> **"Excel has stopped working and is looking for a solution"**

message. This message lasts a few seconds, meanwhile Excel is closing, causing the hang on the file to occur and my tests to throw an exception like

> **"Cannot access file because it is being used by another process..."**

message. Otherwise, each of my tests run individually just fine!

Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Do I overuse the `ApplicationClass.Quit()` method?

Quitting Excel only once the testing is through with my tests causes the files created for the tests purpose not to be deleteable.

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've made changes to the `Workbook` then could it be the "Do you wish to save changes?" dialog which is holding things up. You could try setting the `_Workbook.Saved` property to `True` prior to quitting the application. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saved.aspx) for details

Comment: +1 How couldn't I have thought about it before! Thanks a lot barrowc! =)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same "Cannot access file because it is being used by another process..." issue.

I was saving the worksheet, what you need to do is save the work book. Here's a full example.

```
private void TestCreateExcel(IEnumerable<Sales1> data)
    {
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        var workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Title";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Author(s)";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "Release Date";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "D"] = "Total Books Sold";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "E"] = "Last 30 Days Sales";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "F"] = "Average Sales Per Month";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "G"] = "Starting Advance";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "H"] = "Current Advance";

        int index = 1; //Keep track of the which row we're writing to.
        foreach (var n in data)
        {
            index++;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "A"] = n.Title;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "B"] = n.Author;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "C"] = n.ReleaseDate.ToShortDateString();
            workSheet.Cells[index, "D"] = n.TotalBooksSold;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "E"] = n.Last30DaysSales;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "F"] = n.AverageSalesPerMonth;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "G"] = n.StartingAdvance;
            workSheet.Cells[index, "H"] = n.CurrentAdvance;
        }

        workBook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath + fileName));
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```